# Subtract two lists in Python without using classes

Tags: python, list, difference

I have two numeric lists, **a**, **b** that I am trying to subtract like this; **b - a**.

I want this to be easy for a beginner to understand so I don't want to import classes or libraries.

**This is what I have tried, and it works:**

```
a = [420, 660, 730, 735] 
b = [450, 675, 770, 930]   
i = 0
j = len(a)
difference = []

while i < j:
    difference.append(b[i] - a[i])
    i += 1
print (difference) 
>>[30, 15, 40, 195]    **the correct result**
```

However, there must be a simpler way of doing this without importing classes or libraries that I am missing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `operator` module provides functional versions of the standard operators for just such an occasion.

```
>>> import operator
>>> a = [420, 660, 730, 735] 
>>> b = [450, 675, 770, 930]   
>>> difference = list(map(operator.sub, b, a))
>>> print(difference)
[30, 15, 40, 195]
```

Answer (score 11):

A simple way to show this would be:

```
a = [420, 660, 730, 735] 
b = [450, 675, 770, 930]


print([v2 - v1 for v1, v2 in zip(a, b)])
```

`zip` will create a tuple between each of the elements in your list. So if you run zip alone you will have this:

```
zip(a, b)

[(420, 450), (660, 675), (730, 770), (735, 930)]
```

Then, to further analyze what is happening in the answer I provided, what you are doing is iterating over each element in your list, and then specifying that `v1` and `v2` are each item in your tuple. Then the `v2 - v1` is pretty much doing your math operation. And all of this is wrapped inside what is called a list comprehension.

If you are still convinced that you still don't want to use zip at all, and if your example is using two equal lists, then what I suggest is to drop the while loop and use a for instead. And your solution will be very similar to what you already have, but as such:

```
n = []
for i, v in enumerate(a):
    n.append(b[i] - v)
print(n)
```

So, you have to create a new list that will hold your new data. Use `enumerate` so you get your index and value through each iteration, and append your math operation to your new list.

Comment: This is a perfect example of how to do this with Python! Exactly what I was looking for and a great explanation as well:D Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Given, your lists `a` and `b`, `b - a` can be evaluated as

```
difference = [each[0] - each[1] for each in zip(b, a)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Taking into account the comment:

Assuming both lists are purely composed of integers:

```
# a and b are the lists
difference = []
for i in range(min(len(b), len(a))):
    difference.append(b[i] - a[i])
```

EDIT: The other list comprehensions are more Pythonic, but this is more in line with the original code

Comment: Small improvement to avoid problem with lists of unequal length: `for i in range(min(len(a),len(b))):`.